# Inbound traffic from ISP's DNS server

Tags: dns

My Symantec end point traffic logs keep showing that inbound UDP traffic from the DNS server is blocked. This happens every few minutes. Is it a potential attack?

Comment: Can you resolve domain names? I guess you would have said if not, but DNS answer are "incoming UDP traffic from DNS server", can you figure out what the endpoint think is "DNS server" (likely is your router, so incoming traffic from your router can be anything, e.g. use netmon to discover what this traffic is)

Comment: Please link to PCAP file.

Comment: I voted to close until there is enough information to post an adequate, informed answer. As it’s currently written, there is just no way to tell.

Answer (score -1):

Probably it is a DOS attack.

Check the log carefully and verify the source IP of the request.

If it is a DOS attack,

the source IP's may look like
either

xxx.xxx.xxx.000
 For all entries
 Or

May be a group

xxx.xxx.xxx.000
xxx.xxx.xxx.001
xxx.xxx.xxx.002

Likewise

If you see random IP address repeatedly, it may be a DDOS attack.

Don't worry the Firewall will take care of it.

If it can't, either down the server by yourself or use a 302 temporary redirect

UPDATE

> The firewall is efficiently preventing it. If you want it not to come, Just add a [302](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_302) for 1 or 2 hours to google.com or something and then remove it.

Comment: It is not random. Just 2 IP addresses. These two keep appearing in the firewall logs.

Comment: updated. Read more about 302 in the link in answer.

Comment: "Every few minutes" doesn't sound like DOS to me.

Comment: @user155462 flood of requests will occur within a minute if it is a DDOS but the case of DOS is different

Comment: @i-- Not really. Both have the goal to flood, the difference is just how many computers try to flood you. (Read more about it at eg. Wikipedia, or here, or...). Otherwise, there is no "denial of service". A request every few minutes won't harm the server in any way.

Comment: This is a horrible answer. There is no reasoning and no obvious chain of arguments from “UDP traffic from my ISP” do DOS. Taking care of DDoS with an endpoint Firewall is ridiculous and a 302 is a http status and has nothing to do with UDP.

Comment: @user155462 not really. A DOS can very well be just one packet, not causing an overload situation but a malfunction that leads to the system becoming unavailable.

Comment: @SmokeDispenser Ok, point to you :) To rephrase, a packet every few minutes is not enough to be considered flooding a webserver.